# Using faisalman:ua-parser-js on Meteor client

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, package

Before filing an issue on it's [github](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js), can't ua-parser-js be used on the client in Meteor? I have added 0.7.9 successfully to my 1.1.0.3 app with `meteor add faisalman:ua-parser-js`. It seems to be exported as `UAParser` in package.js [here](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/blob/master/package.js), for both client and server. Still, I can't seem to acccess it? See [this MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/iq9RdbNB2mGdPuKpk/ua-parser-js) for examples of what I've tried.

UPDATE: [Issue](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/issues/137) filed on GitHub. Also note that I recommend feature detection. ;)